# Remove illegal characters from a string of XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have a string containing some XML. For example:

```
<foo>
    <bar>this is < than this</bar>
</foo>
```

and I need to remove the illagal characters from it before I load it into an `XmlDocument`.

any thoughts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

> I have a string containing some Xml.

No you don't. You have some XML-like text that is not well-formed. Once it's all glued together like that, it's hard work finding the special characters. Oh, you could try to look for "< " or " >", but those could appear anyway. My advice is to go back a step and look where that string came from. Change that code so it deals with special characters.

In the absence of any other options, I would probably ignore XML tools for the moment (because they'll throw up when you try to give them the string) and do some sort of running count of open/close (odd/even for quotes) on special characters. Once you've encountered an <, you aren't allowed another one until you meet a >, for example. Unfortunately you can't use < and the like in attributes, so I don't know what you'll do with `<foo p1="a<a">` but at least you could fix `<foo>a<A</foo>`. (Assuming they would never put a < in a tag name, meeting the second one means you need to back up and escape the first one.) Once you've encountered a >, you can't have another one. And so on. My sympathies.

Comment: I get your point, if this was an option I would have already done it

Comment: So you didn't write the code that made the string? You have some sort of contract with another app, and it's supposed to give you XML but it's not? Push on that. You are setting yourself up a really hard task. Consider `<foo p1="ha>ha" />` for example.

Comment: No nothing like that, I'm looking at the possibility of getting round this by parsing the text before it gets to this stage but without explaining the complexities of the app's this is one of the best places for stripping illegal characters. Believe me... I know this is going to be a pain in the arse either way

Comment: I can sympathise with the OP here, Kate.  I once had to work with data from a large and very well known hardware and software company, supposedly in a CSV file.  The data was comma separated and quote delimited, but included quote marks and commas in the data items.  It was hard enough to parse by eye, let alone write a parser that could cope with it automatically.  The vender (being who they were) would not change the format, so we had to make best efforts to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do here is to make intelligent guesses about what you are likely to see, and try to handle them as best you can.  The most important thing is to make sure that if your rules fail, you don't damage other data - aborting gracefully without doing anything and alerting the admin is usually not ideal, but the best you're likely to get.

In the example you gave, there seems to be a space after the < within the data string is followed by whitespace, whereas the < that forms part of the tags isn't.  Can you exploit that?

In my experience of working with files that don't meet the spec they're supposed to, you have to work with the little crumbs that you're given, and pray to whatever deity you chose that things won't unravel further.

Sorry. ;)

EDIT --

One more thing that has just occurred to me...  Is the data you're working with in a rigidly pre-defined format?  Is it going to have optional parameters in the tags, for example?  If not, you can probably be really sneaky (and make hardened developers weep slightly) by making use of the schema.

eg - if you know you're always going to get tags like this

```
<myData>
  <MyFirstTag>Hello, I contain illegal < data</MyFirstTag>
  <moreData>and I am just plain <B>stupid</B></moreData>
</myData>
```

you can try to tokenise the field definitions with some known and unique string (maybe a guid?)

```
knownstring1
  knownstring2Hello, I contain illegal < dataendknownstring2
  knownstring3and I am just plain <B>stupid</B>endknownstring3
endknownstring1
```

then you can do the replacement on the illegal characters, and then put the tags back ready to import into an XMLDocument.

I know, it makes me shudder, too, but sometimes the data you are given needs you to resort to dirty hacks.

Comment: That, just, might, work... It may be a little trickier than that but I think you've given me something to work with. I'll have to try in the morning when I have a clearer head. Thanks

Comment: Ps. I will be abstracting this lovely piece of code well away from any other developers. It can be our dirty secret

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common scenario working with markup that has been bequeathed to you one way or another. 2  general possibilities:

1) The markup is generated by buggy code that you may or may not have access to. You are likely to find that bad spots are repetitive and predictable and you can abate the problems with your own code: regexes etc. In the happy case where you *can* fix the generating code, obviously fix that.

2) The markup is generated by people who don't know/care what they are doing. This is a  people problem. Don't attempt to fix it with code. You have to handle it by talking to the people who are doing it and handle the politics one way or another. Look at the bright side,  maybe you can get your boss to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tool to fix the errors in the xml you have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# Fixes unescaped "<" and "&" in between tags.

use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode qw( encode decode );

sub fix_xml {
    my ($broken_xml) = @_;

    my $enc;
    if    ( $_[0] =~ /^\xEF\xBB\xBF/ ) { $enc = 'UTF-8';    }
    elsif ( $_[0] =~ /^\xFF\xFE/     ) { $enc = 'UTF-16le'; }
    elsif ( $_[0] =~ /^\xFE\xFF/     ) { $enc = 'UTF-16be'; }
    elsif (substr($_[0], 0, 100) =~ /^[^>]* encoding="([^"]+)"/) { $enc = $1; }
    else                               { $enc = 'UTF-8';    }

    $broken_xml = decode($enc, $_[0], Encode::FB_CROAK | Encode::LEAVE_SRC);

    my $name   = qr/(?:\w+:)?\w+/x;
    my $value  = qr/(?: '[^']+' | "[^"]+" )/x;
    my $s      = qr/\s/x;
    my $attrib = qr/$name $s* = $s* $value/x;

    my $fixed_xml = '';
    for ($broken_xml) {
        /\G \z /xcg && last;

        /\G ( (?: [^<&]+ | &\#?\w+; )+               ) /xscg && do { $fixed_xml .= $1; redo };  # Text
        /\G ( < $name (?: $s+ $attrib )* $s* \/? >   ) /xscg && do { $fixed_xml .= $1; redo };  # Start or empty tag
        /\G ( <\/ $name $s* >                        ) /xscg && do { $fixed_xml .= $1; redo };  # End tag
        /\G ( <!-- (?:(?! -- ).)* -->                ) /xscg && do { $fixed_xml .= $1; redo };  # Comment
        /\G ( <!\[CDATA\[ (?:(?! \]\]> ).)* \]\]>    ) /xscg && do { $fixed_xml .= $1; redo };  # CDATA
        /\G ( <? $s* $name (?: $s+ $attrib )* $s* ?> ) /xscg && do { $fixed_xml .= $1; redo };  # Decl

        # Something illegal!
        /\G ( < ) /xscg && do { $fixed_xml .= "&#lt;";  redo };  # Unescaped "<"
        /\G ( & ) /xscg && do { $fixed_xml .= "&#amp;"; redo };  # Unescaped "&"

        die("Don't know how to fix character at position " . pos() . "\n");
    }

    return encode($enc, $fixed_xml);
}

die("usage: $0 file.xml") if !@ARGV || $ARGV[0] eq '/?' || $ARGV[0] eq '-h' || $ARGV[0] eq '--help';

my $broken_xml;
{
    open(my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0])
       or die("Can't open \"$ARGV[0]\": $!\n");
    binmode($fh);
    local $/;
    $broken_xml = <$fh>;
}

binmode(STDOUT);
print fix_xml($broken_xml);
```

It doesn't detect all problems (e.g. unescaped "&" in attributes), but it does detect and fix the problem you're asking about.

Untested.

Comment: Arghh Perl :S I'm a C# man and this could be a nightmare to convert... is it possible?

Comment: @mjmcloug, Why convert it? C# can surely launch programs, or you could fix them before passing them to your program in the first place.